What's wrong with adding the derivative of an equation to my system of ODEs?
It's been too long since I've taken or used my differential equations class, so you'll have to be patient if I am missing terminology, or some obvious solution. Suppose I have a system of differential equations in $d$, $i$, and $v$. (it makes no difference to the math, but these are distance, current, and voltage). I want to solve this numerically, so I'm writing a function that given $U$ returns $dU$, where $U$ is a vector $<d,d',i,v>$ and $dU$ is $<d',d'',i',v'>$. I have 3 equations.
$$ i' = f(d',i,v) $$
$$ d'' = g(d,i) $$
$$ v' = h(i) $$
because I'm a moron I forgot I can just pass through $d'$, and I don't need a separate equation for it. (or equivalently, I can use a substitution, $d' = b$, which will be my equation). So I tried to find an equation for $d'$, and I argued like this:
I can rearrange the equation for $i'$ to get something like $d' = j(i',i,v)$. But now $d'$ depends on a variable that's not in $U$. I can take the derivative of $i'$. So $i''=f'(d'',d',i,i',v,v')=f'(g(d,i),d',i,i',v,h(i))$. Because I made substitutions for $d''$ and $v'$, $i''$ only depends on $i,i',d,d',$ and $v$. Of these only $i'$ is not in $U$. But since we have an equation for $i''$, why not just add $i'$ into $U$ and $i''$ into $dU$? So $U$ would be $<d,d',i,i',v>$ and $dU$ would be $<d',d'',i',i'',v'>$.
Ultimately, this does not produce the same results as the correct solution where $d' = b$. But I don't know why. Other than being needlessly complex, what's wrong with this argument?
(I don't think it's necessary to answer the question, but here's the system, where r, C, and k's are all just constants with the right units).
$$v=-i/C$$
$$i' = \frac{v-ir-id'k_1}{ik_2}$$
$$d'' = i^2k_3M(d)$$
$$M(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{X-x}{r_n\sqrt{r_n^2+(X-x)^2}} + \frac{x^2}{r_n\sqrt{r_n^2+x^2}}$$

Taking the derivative of $i'=f(d',i,v)$ leads to a profusion of terms because of the chain rule: $i''=d''\partial_{d'}f+i'\partial_{i}f+v'\partial_v f$. I dont know much about numerics, but a typical way to phrase your initial system as a first order one would be to introduce a new unknown function $D=d'$ which replaces your second equation with two equations: $D'=g$ and $d'=D$. You will need 4 initial conditions to propagate the solution, which makes sense even with your 3 initial equations because one of them is second order

If the above comment makes sense, then the next issue is: probably your equations become singular at some point, and it is not simple to impose initial conditions at this singular point

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Sal, I think we've misunderstood eachother, and perhaps it is my fault. d,i, and v are functions of time, and all the derivatives are with respect to time. I'm (quite thankfully) not dealing with partial derivatives.

@Sal, it's not so much a problem that there is a singularity. I could just enter values arbitrarily close to the singularity, no problem. The problem is, very near the singularity, d' has an equation that implies a very large value. But if we integrate d'', we get a value close to zero. These two things are in contradiction.

This post is too long to read.
It is total standard to introduce a new variable $b$ and transform the system
\begin{align}\tag1
i'&=f(d',i,v)\,,&d''&=g(d,i)\,,&v'&=h(i)\,
\end{align}
to
\begin{align}\tag2
i'&=f(b,i,v)\,,&d'&=b\,,&b'&=g(d,i)\,,&v'&=h(i)\,.
\end{align}
In your special case, $f(d',i,v)$ can be drastically simplified using $v=-i/C\,:$
$$\tag3
i'= \frac{v-ir-id'k_1}{ik_2}=\frac{-1}{Ck_2}-\frac{r+d'k_1}{k_2}
$$
which leads to
$$\tag4
i(t)=i(0)-\frac{(1+Cr)\,t}{Ck_2}-\frac{k_1}{k_2}(d(t)-d(0))\,.
$$
This means that only the equation involving $M(d)$ has to be solved numerically and that does not look singular to me.

You're right, my question was too long, and was really many different questions. I've tried to edit the question down to only one question and seperate out the other. And I really appreciate your help solving this system. Now that you point it out, I like your simplification. But ultimately the question is, will adding the derivative of one of the equations over determine the system?

Also, I didn't explicitly substitute d'=b. But you'll notice I did include d' in the vector U, so as far as getting a numerical solution goes, it really is the same thing, right? I don't see how this substitution solves the problem that I don't have an equation for b, except in terms of i', which is not in the vector U. Isn't that a problem?

Your post is still too long. The two systems (1) and (2) I wrote in this answer are identical ways of writing down what you have to solve. You should try to understand why that is the case. If it is not obvious I believe that pretty much every book about ODEs discusses that.

I understand that (1) and (2) are identical. That's my complaint. It doesn't solve my problem. I can write U=<i,d,b,v> and dU=<i',d',b',v'>. But I still don't have an equation for d' except in terms of i'. But You're right, it's still too long. I'll edit it down more.

The equation for $d'$ is $d'=b,.$

I'm having a dawning realization that I've been an idiot this entire time. Of course. I've been WAY overthinking this.  your way is simpler and obviously correct and I cannot express how much of a moron I am to have missed this, especially given that I've literally taken a class on this and that's like the most basic thing. But I'm still left with this question: what was wrong with solving the problem my way (other than it was needlessly complex).

The system (2) should be easy to solve numerically. What you describe as your way I don't understand.
